# Cakephp displaying application status

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a referral plugin, whenever a link is sent to a user a recorded will be added to the table with a default id of 0 whenever the invited user registered using the referral link the id will be automatically increased. I am trying to display the application status using if statement but noticed that it working with the last id and not each user id.

```
    <?php foreach ($rlinks as $rlink)  ?>
    <div>
     <?php $uimail = $rlink['invite']['new_user_id'];
    $uuuu = 0;
    if ($uimail > $uuuu) {
    echo "registerd";                     
    } else {
    echo "not registered";
   }
   ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It displays not registered for all users

Comment: You are showing an open brace on the `foreach`, but using `endforeach`, that should be a syntax error. You are not showing where `$invite` comes from. You never use the `$rlink` variable. Is this your actual code?

Comment: The open brace & $invite are typos I have replaced the $invite with $rlink and also removed the open brace, I am still having the same issue

Comment: This is probably still not exactly your code, because you don't have a `:` at the end of your `foreach` line. If we can't trust that this is exactly the code that's running, we can't reliably help with fixing it; the problem might well be some other typo!

Answer (score 0):

**First fix typos:**

`<?php foreach ($rlinks as $rlink) { ?>` would be:
`<?php foreach ($rlinks as $rlink): ?>`

and

`$invite['invite']['new_user_id'];`would be: `$rlink['invite']['new_user_id'];`

then:

```
<?php foreach ($rlinks as $rlink): ?>
    <div>
     <?php 
        $uimail = $rlink['invite']['new_user_id'];
        echo $uimail > 0 ? "registerd" : "not registered";
     ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**debug() output is your friend!**

```
<?php debug($rlinks); ?>
```

Comment: I tried it still displays not registered for everyone, I shared my links to 3 people 2 have registered while 1 has not register.

Comment: @IsaiahOladapo add debug output to your question.